# Почему в реестре некоторые разделы называются цифрами и буквами?

Tags: реестр

{59031A47-3F72-44A7-89C5-5595FE6B30EE} - скажите, почему некоторые разделы имеют в реестре такие названия. Я думаю, что это шестнадцатеричная система счисления. Если так, то что эти названия могут значить, и можно ли их перевести на родной язык?

Comment: Это GUID, а вот что он значит, нужно смотреть в документации к тому месту, где он используется

Comment: Конкретно этот GUID используется в Проводнике для обозначения домашней папки пользователя (но внятной документации на эту тему я почему-то не нашёл)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данные названия - это [guid](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID). Они нужны для уникальности. Их нельзя перевести на "родной язык", так как это не связанно с названием или описанием. Это просто сгенерированный ключ.

GUID расшифровывается как глобально уникальный идентификатор. Это 128-битная структура, которая, по задумке, гарантирует, что ключ не повторится.

Comment: Спасибо большое!